# Angular 4 (MEAN) app working fine on PC(All Browser), but cant open on mobile browser

Tags: node.js, angular

http://49.xx.xx.xxx:3000 
angular 4 app is running on pc fine in all browsers, but when i opens this app in mobile device, below error shows me on android mobile browser.

This site can't be reached 49.xx.xx.xxx:3000 took long respond.

Try:
    Checking the Connection
    ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT

Comment: Is your mobile on the same network as your computer?

Comment: Is not the network problem? Are you in the same mobile segment as a PC? Do I get a mobile IP address from my PC? Not a PC firewall?

Comment: Why does your question look copy pasted from another source and includes recommendations what to check?

Comment: @david no there are different networks i used in both devices, but in pc app opens fine but not on mobile device.

Comment: So you can access other urls on 49.xxx from your mobile, but just not that one ?

Comment: @david - no i cannot access other url's from 49.xx.xx.xxx server to mobile, but one thing this server is http:// not secure any problems facing for this topic?

Comment: @ketan well that's the problem then. If your computer is on an entreprise network which your phone cannot access, you won't be able to test

Comment: ohh thanks david, for help but what can i do for solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your computer routes back your 49.xx.xx.xxx ip to localhost. When you are accessing it via mobile phone your computer blocks the connection. Try to start angular serve with the --host parameter

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

or

```
ng serve --host 49.xx.xx.xxx
```